# Accessing information from a file dependent on another file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloud

Hai i want to write a MapReduce program which takes two files as input ,( for eg : 
file1 : Account Details
file2 : Transaction Details) and take the account details from the file1 and access the corresponding account transaction details from file2. Here files are dependent if we want to access transaction details we need particular account details..Assuming that both files are in a single folder and that folder is passing as input to the map reduce program.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The two datasets have to be joined, this is a very common scenario. Check [MapReduce Design Patterns Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025122.do) on how to do the joins. Here is the corresponding [code](https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/tree/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5) for joining. Also, check [Data-Intensive Text Processing with MapReduce](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/) for the different patterns around joins.

Comment: Hi sir, For this code what type of input files we use? xml files or Text Files.

Comment: Data can be in any format based on the source. Not exactly sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use case for the distributed cache feature in Hadoop. You use the larger file as input to your MapReduce job and put the smaller one on the Distributed Cache. This way you can access data from both files in the Mapper code.

Please refer to the [Distributed Cache API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) for more information on how to use it.